# floating point division in C language

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>   
float t, delt = 0.004000,n;

printf("enter the value for t=");
scanf("%f", &t);
n = t/ delt;
printf("n is %f",n);
getch();
```

output:
enter the value for t=1
n is 249.999985

I am expecting 250. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Perhaps SO should put a link to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) page as a sticky at the top

Comment: SO should automatically look for dups before posting.  Like bugzilla does

Answer (score 3):

You are up against the all-too-common problem that [floating point representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) are approximations.  You may wish to do one of the following:

- [Round your answer](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html) using an unbiased rounding strategy.
- Truncate your answer to zero decimal places before printing it (using something like `%.0f`).
- Use an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Which one of these is sensible is entirely dependent on the constraints of your application.